# Default bash prompt hex value for 16.04

Tags: command-line, bash

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and enabled prompt colors in the terminal (it isn't default for 14.04 and that setting stayed with me through the upgrade).  The problem is that I don't quite know what color it should be.  Everything I try seems a bit off.  Can someone who installed a fresh version of 16.04 give me the hex value?  Instructions to find it are as follows:

1. Open Terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
2. Click on Edit>Profile Preferences
3. Click on Colours
4. Click the box circled below

[image: box to click]

5. Give me the value circled below

[image: value to give]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default color for the Ubuntu bash is `#8AE234`

[image: Ubuntu_Bash]